# Why mysql is not using index on join?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-execution-plan

I have the two tables named A and B. My query for explain SQL is:

```
explain select * from A k join P p1 on p1.aggregate_id=k.aggregate_id where p1.start=1 and p1.id= 123 \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: k
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: idx_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 23
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p1
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_id
          key: idx_id
      key_len: 17
          ref: const,db.k.agreegate_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where

In table A the idx is index on aggregate_id.
In table B, idx is index on aggregate_id,start,id
```

Why the index from table A is not getting used?

I am testing on my dev box and there are 20 entries approx, in each table

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle

Comment: with just 20 entries, just reading the table directly is faster than using an index.  try with a more realistic amount of data

Comment: mysql.. I need to take these changes to my production system and my dev box wont have enough data but production will definitely have. Can i assume that production will use indexes and the results will be faster ?

Comment: unless there's something wrong with your indexes, yes.  output of `show create table A` and `show create table P` would be helpful.  I am a little surprised it didn't start reading p1 by id; is id not the primary key of P?

Comment: you can always just run the explain in production

Comment: id is not primary key P, that is some different  and there is index on that too, but i have not shown here to keep only relavant.   I dont have index on production, i have to get them by testing on dev system first.

Comment: If this is for MySQL, why did you tag it as 'oracle'?  While MySQL is owned by the Oracle Corporation, the MySQL RDBMS product is distinct from the Oracle RDBMS product.  The two are not the same and are not interchangeable.  .

Comment: will take care of oracle vs mysql next time